# Conditional Breakpoint failed

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints, autodesk, revit-api, conditional-breakpoint

I'm creating a dll in c# which will be an addin for a host application, Revit. I've set a conditional breakpoint in my code while attempting to debug some issues. This is my debugging process:

- Build my dll
- Post build events copy the new files to appropriate addin folders
- I launch Revit manually and open a file I'm using for testing
- In Visual Studio I select Debug -> Attach to Process -> Revit.exe
- I click the button in Revit to launch the command.

I'm running Visual Studio 2022 professional edition in admin mode while Revit is running in user mode (ie not admin mode).

The code runs fine when there is no breakpoint. When I set a conditional breakpoint I get the error below. What I'm attempting to do is hit the breakpoint once a specific string is "volume"

Any light that can be shed on the topic would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you do not start Revit.exe externally, but instead set it as a start-up program in the Visual Studio debug settings. Then you do not need to attach to process. That is what I always do.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for your suggestions, they are always valuable. I used to start revit as you suggested, as a start-up program, but when I run visual studio in admin mode this launches revit under the admin user and therefore I am unable to debug the application under typical user settings. This can lead me to some false positives. I did research if it was possible to launch start-up programs in non-admin mode while running visual studio in admin mode, but it doesn’t seem possible, hence why I’m doing it as I mentioned above.

Comment: How about running Visual Studio in non-admin mode too?  That's what I do.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for the suggestion. When I run VS in non-admin mode I am unable to run post-build events (IT security policy blocks batch scripts). When I run VS in admin mode I am not blocked by IT policies.

Comment: Maybe you can split the debugging and post-build stuff into separate steps?